# Xen DomU does not have network connectivity

Tags: networking, xen

I am trying to install Xen on my Fedora box. Dom0 image has network connectivity. But when I try to create a DomU, it does not have network connectivity.

I want to be able to run in bridged mode. I have the /etc/xend/xend-config.sxp file accordingly. My config file looks like

`kernel = "/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-xenU" 
memory = 64
name = "clientA"
vif = ['bridge=xenbr0,mac=12.34.56.78.9A.BC']
root = "/dev/sda1 ro"
ramdisk = "/boot/initrd-linux.img"
extra = "ro selinux=0.3 initcall_debug"
features = 'auto_translated_physmap'`

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended and also default in Xen 4.1+ to setup the network bridges using the networking scripts in the distro scripts. You would then disable the bridge code in the xend config (in 4.1+ xend is deprecated).

You can follow these instructions for "Red Hat-style bridge configuration (e.g. RHEL, Fedora, CentOS)"
http://new-wiki.xen.org/wiki/HostConfiguration/Networking

To troubleshoot in general you can use the brctl tool.

For example,

```
brctl show
```